# meta tags not appearing

Tags: 7, meta-tags

I am using Drupal 7, and I have strange problem with meta tags. For some content type even if I enter meta title, meta keywords and description, they don't get effective on page.

Where in for some content type it does reflect the meta information.

How can I narrow down the problem? I have no idea how I can make use of meta tag quick module for my problem because meta information is not getting generated.

How can I debug where the problem exists?

Answer (score 2):

I searched for this a while and found some solutions.

The thing is make sure you have rendered the `<?php print render($page['content']['metatags']); ?>` in page--front.tpl.php

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel). This should help you debug and narrow down the problem.

Comment: I would use the Devel module too, probably starting in Theme preprocess functions (for html) to see if something is overriding the data, then working up to module functions & hooks.

Answer (score 0):

do you use display suite on the content type where you have problem. If yes, you should read [this post](http://drupal.org/node/1284852) and apply the patch. You must use the full display and not the default display to get the meta tags on yours pages.